# jquery dialog draggable and resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my div draggable and resizable using jquery.
Here is a simple div:

```
<div id="dialog-modal-alerts" title="Alerts" style="display:none;"></div>
```

and this is how I use jquery:

```
$("#dialog-modal-alerts").dialog({
            height: 500,
            width: 900,
            title: strTitle,
            resizable:true,
            draggable:true,
            dialogClass: "alertDialog",
            //buttons: [{ text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } }],
            close: function (event, ui) { closeDialog(number) },
            modal: true
        });
```

And it doesn't work.
It works if I write

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog-modal-alerts").draggable();
    });
```

But if I write

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog-modal-alerts").resizable();
    });
```

it's still not working
Can anybody help with my issue?

Comment: What do you expect how it should work?

Comment: I want to dragg my div and change it size.

Comment: By default, the dialog is both: http://jsfiddle.net/7RtL7/

Comment: @j08691 You are rigth but it doesn't work by default and I don't know why

Comment: Have you included jquery UI?  That is where all of these things come from.

Comment: @ James Montagne Sure.

Answer (score 3):

did you check this? it's by default draggable dialog and resizable

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

it's about strTitle try to remove it and add 'Title' or anything and close(number) make sure number and strTitle exists as valid variables.

i created this example i working fine:

```
    <div id="dialog-modal-alerts" title="Alerts" style="display:none;">

        Hlllo
        Ahmed Alaa<br />

    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $("#dialog-modal-alerts").dialog({
              height: 500,
              width: 900,
              title: 'Hi',
              resizable: true,
              draggable: true,
              dialogClass: "alertDialog", 
              modal: true
          });
      });
```

Comment: Yes,I cheked this.As you see my answer above,I suppose that it wil be draggable and resizable but it doesn't

Comment: try to remove the draggable function and leave the resizable ,maybe something goes wrong when adding both

Comment: it's about strTitle try to remove it and add 'Title'

Comment: I don't think so,as I've got the same idea)I delete this string an nothing changed

Comment: also the number value closeDialog(number)? the above example try copy and paste it and it's working to make sure that this is the error.

Comment: this is just a part of my function,there isn't any ttroubles with number

Comment: is it a global variable?

Comment: @ Ahmed Alaa El-Din I pass it as parametr to the method where I show my dialog-modal-alerts

Comment: try to comment this close or insert number manually for now and try ,does your page has any other javascript function or loading in jquery library?

Comment: @ Ahmed Alaa El-Din I tryed to remove and to insert number manually,there wasn'tany effects
yes,there are some js functions

Comment: maybe something inside your javascript ,prevent these to work as they should ...do you have Web developer toolbar?

Comment: hmm that's strange, probably something prevent it to work. maybe you can disbale any other javascript right now and try it or create another page that does this dialog only and try it

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that there is something broken in one of your functions that you haven't shown us, possibly a syntax error, that keeps it from finishing the code. I say this because I can successfully execute your snippet and achieve the desired behavior. Perhaps my full [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kWXzARcH) will help.

Note that separately calling

```
$("#dialog-modal-alerts").draggable();
```

is expected to work, since this is a documented jquery ui method. You can mark any item as draggable, whether or not it is a modal dialog, and that's what you've done.

On the other hand,

```
$("#dialog-modal-alerts").resizable();
```

is not expected to work, since resizable is not it's own function.

Comment: Thanks,I will try this.
But are you shure that resizable isn't jquery own function?
See the link below:
http://jqueryui.com/resizable/